# Does image augmentation helps?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, classification

I am trying to build cnn model (keras) that can classify image based on users emotions. I am having issues with data. I have really small data for training. Will augmenting data help? Does it improve accuracy? In which case one should choose to augment data and should avoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will augmenting data help? Does it improve accuracy?

That's hard to say in advance. But almost certainly, when you already have a model which is better than random. And when you choose the right augmentation method.

See my masters thesis [Analysis and Optimization of Convolutional Neural Network Architectures](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.09725.pdf#page=94), page 80 for many different augmentation methods.

> In which case one should choose to augment data and should avoid?

- When you don't have enough data -> augment
- Avoid augmentations where you can't tell the emotion after the augmentation. So in case of character recognition, rotation is a bad idea (e.g. due to `6 vs 9` or `u vs n` or `\rightarrow vs \nearrow`)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, data augmentation really helps, and sometimes it's really necessary. (But take a look at Martin Thoma's answer, there are more details there and some important "take-cares").

You should use it when:

- You have too little data
- You notice your model is overfitting too easily (may be a model too powerful too)

Overfitting is something that happens when your model is capable of memorizing the data. Then it gets splendid accuracy for training data, but terrible accuracy for test data.

Increasing the size of training data will make it more difficult for your model to memorize. Small changes here and there will make your model stop paying attention to details that don't mean anything (but are capable of creating distinctions between images) and start paying attention to details that indeed cause the desired effect.

Comment: does zooming, scaling and rotating is enough for augmentation or we can also play around with channels and histogram equalization?

Comment: You can't say if some augmentations are enough without trying it. The more interesting question is if they improve the model at all. And that is also very problem, model and dataset specific (+1 for the answer)

Comment: Indeed, @MartinThoma.